# GenericUDF's initialized method being called multiple times

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, hive-udf

I've a HiveUDF which extends GenericUDF, when I call the udf via spark.sql I am getting the correct results but the initialized method is called multiple times.

Can't understand why that's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a spark bug here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17728 .

You can try `cache()` the data before applying the UDF, but some times this workaround costs performance.